# Movie Clip Editor Multiple Masks

Tags: node-editor, compositing-nodes, masking, movie-clip-editor, id-mask

New to Blender, have a quick question about masking.  I am greenscreening some photos, however some areas do not cut out correctly (space between ladder notches), so I have resorted to masking and using nodes in Compositor.  I was able to add a mask around the object via Movie Clip Editor, however when I add another mask to the space between the ladders (adding a square between), this second mask does not show and the greenscreen is still visible.  I am using nodes similar to how CG Geek on Youtube has in his tutorial.  A second mask option does not appear when I include another Mask input.  Any help is appreciated!

Comment: if there is no second mask in the list, maybe you have a single mask with two areas. in this case you need 1 mask node in the compositor. you can add more than one area in the mask.

Comment: I have added a second area, but the second area does not show in the first mask.  I am adding a second mask, how would it connect in the keying or AlphaOver nodes?

Comment: you can add two masks with color add node. the result is both masks white in black background. so you can use it as alpha over input.